# Unable to execute dot command after installation of Graphviz. (There is no layout engine support for "dot")

Tags: graphviz

I'm working on a Ubuntu system and installed the Graphviz library with:

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

As **dot** comes with it by default when I'm running the dot command, it gives me:

```
There is no layout engine support for "dot"
Perhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's privileges) to register the plugins?
```

Or when I run the whole command like:

```
dot -Tsvg test.gv -O
```

This produces below error:

```
Format: "svg" not recognized. No formats found.
Perhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's privileges) to register the plugins?
```

I tried the command given here in the terminal **dot -c**/**sudo dot -c** but didn't work for me. Also, search for the solution of it, which ends up with the same answer, which is to use *dot -c*.

I tried reinstalling it several times but ends up with the same error. I used Graphviz previously as well without any problem. Don't know if I'm missing something this time.

So, How can I resolve this?

Comment: This seems to be a post-installer bug.  I think this problem most commonly shows up on Windows systems.  Here is the "best" example on a Linux system, and it is from 2010 - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=575797.  Did you try **sudo apt purge graphviz; sudo apt install graphviz**

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Are there any "useful" apt error messages?

Comment: No errors while installing.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had the **exact** same errors on MacOS using homebrew to install graphviz. It seems like this problem is caused by a missing dependency, although there is not good feedback on what exactly is missing.

These commands (again, Mac - not your platform but context may be helpful) fixed it for me:

```
brew install libtool
brew link libtool
brew install graphviz
brew link --overwrite graphviz
```

Specifically, I don't think libtool was installed/linked correctly.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu?  (lsb_release -a)